# Worklight: BB9900 - Application launches by displaying splash screen for long duration

Tags: html, css, blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a Hybrid Application using IBM Worklight, JQueryMobile, HTML5 and CSS3. I am facing the following issue:

Application launches by displaying splash screen for long duration.
Initially the application was taking 20-30 seconds to launch.

After which I implemented, minification of js and css files. Now, the duration has come down to 10 seconds. But, this duration is not acceptable.

Is there any other way to tune the BB9900 application?

Note: The same application does not have any issue in BB Z10, Q10 or Android devices.

Comment: Is this on every start? or just the first time you start the application after install.

Comment: The behavior is observed in each launch.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that youv'e reached the limit of what you can do with an older device running BB OS7 (older WebKit engine, too).

Maybe you could also set connectOnStartup to false so that the application will not try to do any connections on startup, and delay any adapter requests until only after the app is ready. Minimize all actions to bare minimum.

You also do not mention your Worklight version. Worklight 6.1.0.x, for example contains a smaller framework footprint and application launch speed improvements.

Comment: connectOnStartup is already set to false. I am using Worklight 6.0